# An infinite family of pairwise independent, jointly dependent random variables

Tags: probability-theory

I'm looking for an explicit example of an infinite sequence of RVs that are pairwise independent yet *not* jointly independent. Could someone please provide a sketch/reference for such a construction?

To clarify, a family of RVs $\{X_i\}_{i \in I}$ is said to be jointly independent if for any finite $J \subset I$ and any choice of Borel sets $B_j$ we have $\mathbb{P}(\forall j: X_j \in B_j) = \prod_j \mathbb{P}(X_j \in B_j)$, and is said to be pairwise independent if the latter holds whenever $|J| = 2$.

I've seen methods that yield finite sequences satisfying this condition, but I'm struggling to generalize them to the infinite case.

Comment: Can't you just pick a family $(X_1,X_2,X_3)$ with that property and choose all other random variables to be constant functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $X_i$ be an independent sequence of random variables in $\mathbb{F}_2$. Define, for every finite $S \subset \mathbb{N}$, $X_S=\sum_{n \in S}{X_n}$. Then the $X_S$ are not jointly independent but they are pairwise independent.